# MSSQL Server Query using correlated query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
Employee(EmployeeNum, Ename, Job, MGR, HireDate, SAL,COMM, DeptNo)
Department (DeptNo, DName, LOC)
```

I am trying to find the following:

Q. Who is the most recently hired employee in each department?

The Query is:

```
SELECT Employee.Ename,
(SELECT MAX(HireDate)
FROM Department
WHERE Employee.DeptNo = Department.DeptNo)
AS HireDate
FROM Employee;
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 112
>   Column 'Employee.Ename' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What is the correct query that will help me to obtain the most recently hired employee from each department?

Thanks!

Comment: Could your provide some sample data and expect result? From your question and query you seem like don't use `Department` table

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL Server (assuming from that error message) you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to get at this pretty easily:

```
SELECT D.DName, E.EName, E.HireDate
FROM
    Department D
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT EmployeeNum, ENAme, HireDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptNo ORDER BY HireDate Desc) as hirerank
            FROM Employee 
        ) E ON D.DeptNo = E.DeptNo
WHERE E.hirerank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `group by` when you are using max condition :

```
     SELECT Ename,
     DeptNo
    , MAX(HireDate)
    FROM Employee
    group by Employee.Ename,DeptNo
```

Comment: I don't see `Hiredate` in the `Department` table in OP's example so this query will error out.

Comment: SELECT Department.DName,
    (SELECT MAX(HireDate)
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Department.DeptNo = Employee.DeptNo)
    AS HireDate
    FROM Department;

Comment: This query works but it only gives me Dname and Hiredate. How can i include EName as well for the output?

Comment: SELECT Department.DName, Ename ,(SELECT EName,MAX(HireDate) FROM Employee WHERE Department.DeptNo = Employee.DeptNo group by Ename) AS HireDate FROM Department roup by Ename,Department.DName

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 139
Invalid column name 'Ename'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 132
Invalid column name 'Ename'.
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 137
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: This is the error message that i get when i run the query you just gave

Comment: SELECT Department.DName ,(SELECT EName,MAX(HireDate) FROM Employee WHERE Department.DeptNo = Employee.DeptNo group by Ename) AS HireDateq FROM Department group by HireDateq.Ename ,Department.DName

Comment: Still giving the same error : Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 149
The multi-part identifier "HireDate.Ename" could not be bound.
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 147
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: i had updated my comment before you try it , check it out , i hope it helps.